# Como faço para colocar uma imagem que vai rolar por cima do background e em baixo do texo?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou aprendendo *HTML* sozinho (fazendo pesquisas e cursos gratuitos na internet), me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho uma imagem de fundo que foi corretamente aplicada, porém não estou conseguindo adicionar outra imagem corretamente, ela está cortada (coloquei uma foto de como ficou), que ficará em baixo do texto e irá rolar junto com o *Scroll* da página, e que fique à cima do background.

[image: Foto mostrando como ficou visualmente.]

**Obs.**: Meu estilo está sendo editado em outro arquivo chamado `estilo.css`, e não diretamente no *HTML*.

**Obs.**: Sou bem iniciante no html e css.

Segue o meu código *CSS*:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-image: url("../_imagens/fundo1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div.logo {
    background-image: url("../_imagens/logoktg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Segue o código do html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ka-Tet Gaming</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo" id="logo">
        <header id="cabecalho">
            <hgroup id="titulo">
                <h1>Seja Bem Vindo ao Site da KTG!</h1>
                <h2>Time Range 1 da PlayerLink.</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A imagem que você quer colocar é esse do logo ?

Comment: Sim, é ela sim. Eu atualizei o post e os códigos, pois consegui colocar a imagem, mas não consegui ajustar ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo jeito o que lhe falta é saber quais propriedade deveria usar.

Para isso recomendo fortemente o seguinte roteiro de estudo:

1. Entenda a propriedade `display` do css

   Ex: Qual diferença entre `inline` e `block` ?
2. Entenda a propriedade `float` do css

   Com o conhecimento de sobre `display` + `float` vc já será capaz de construir um `layout` completo para um página.
3. Entenda a propriedade `position` do css

   Com o conhecimento de sobre `display` + `float`+ `position` vc já será capaz de construir um `layout` completo idenpendente se for para web, celular, tv...

---

Vou tentar fazer uma analogia para tentar ajuda:

Um site é igual a uma casa.

**`HTML`** é igual a um [parede sem reboco](http://www.kimage.com.br/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/72f1a4235c7aca6c735077225f5dacf7/b/a/banner_20111107_23580058cb7258befef275fb17a4775bebe5a9.jpg)

**`CSS`** é igual a [reboco+decoração](http://blog.mpozenato.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/tendencias-decoracao-para-casa.png)

**`Javascipt`** é igual a  [rightec](http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/51/590x/high-tech-retirement-623391.jpg)

**`HTML`** + **`CSS`**  + **`Javascrip`**  se complementão

Comment: Mas estudar CSS não iria atrapalhar o meu conhecimento em HTML?
Pergunto isso por que a maioria das pessoas que são programadores, dizem que se eu quero estudar programação,  devo começar por HTML, como falei, sou bem iniciante em programação, por isso estou cometendo bastante erros kkk
Mas obrigado por já ter me falado que se eu aprender o que passou, vou saber consertar esse erro que estou tendo. Agradeço de verdade !!

Comment: fiz um update  na resposta

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!